# Is there a way to tell which exact enum I'm working with at run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums

I have two enums and a generic method. The generic type T could be either one of the enums.

```
    public enum myEnumA
    {
        a,
        b
    }

    public enum myEnumB
    {
        c,
        d
    }

    public void myMethod<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) is myEnumA)
        {
            //do something
        } 
        else if (typeof (T) is myEnumB)
        {
            //do something else
        }
    }
```

The compiler tells me "the given expression is never of the provided type" regarding the if check.
Is there a way to tell which exact enum it is at run time?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyEnumA))
```

to compare the types. The `is` operator is for testing whether a *value* is of a particular type.

Note that having to test for particular types within a generic method suggests that it might not really be very generic after all - consider using overloads or just entirely separate methods instead.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I need to refresh the basics:)

Answer (score 1):

Because `typeof` returns a `Type` instance and that will never be compatible with your enum types. So `is` will return always false. Instead you need

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(myEnumA))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(myEnumA))
```

Your types are enums, which are sealed.  Were your types not sealed, you might need to use the [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, to check for subclassing, e.g.:

```
if (typeof(BaseTypeA).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```